# Cofactor Expression Confusion

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is: "Find an example of a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ with $C_{22} = -2$, $C_{11} = 6$, and $C_{32} = -2$."

This is a bit confusing, we've not done a problem with the 3 minors in my class.

My Answer:
$$\left[\begin{matrix}
-1 &\pi &1\\
 1 &3  &3\\
 1 &2  &4\\
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
I'm certain this is wrong, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: If you gave another attempt we'd maybe see what you difficulty is ..

Comment: I'm just not sure if what I'm doing is correct.  Is my first attempt answer correct or incorrect?

Comment: If $C_{22}$ is what I think it is -- and you don't tell us -- then I'd get $C_{22}=(-1)(4)-(1)(1)=-5$.

Comment: This isn't what the question is asking.  We are supposed to build a matrix based off of the values initially presented.  That matrix in the top isn't part of the problem, it's my actual answer.  The problem isn't asking us to compute those values.

Comment: I know that, and I am showing you that it won't do. Why don't you tell us properly what you mean by $C_{ij}$ for a matrix $(a_{ij})$? Maybe we  (and you) would then see what equations we had to guess a solution for.